# Calculate SVG Dimensions after rotating a path

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, css-transforms

The question is how to get from the `START SVG` dimensions (without rotation) from the `END SVG` dimensions (with rotation) using maths and only by knowing the `START SVG` informations.
Basically to go from the `START SVG` to the `END SVG` I need to perform a `rotation` of `-115.609deg`.

Here is what I thought about

Retrieve each point from the path and then apply rotation to each point

The START SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="92" height="63" viewBox="0 0 92 63" fill="none">
    <path d="M90.6668 0H0L49.9325 61.7586L90.6668 0Z" fill="#6F7800" />
</svg>
```

The END SVG (That's what I'm trying to achieve but using maths), this is 100% percent accurate

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75" height="83" viewBox="0 0 75 83" fill="none">
    <path d="M90.6668 0H0L49.9325 61.7586L90.6668 0Z" transform="translate(40.1452 82.6093) rotate(-115.609)" fill="#6F7800" />
</svg>
```

Comment: what's the point? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'am trying to find the formula after rotating the path from the first svg

Comment: What  is the math between the first svg and the second

Comment: Why do you care? What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: My problem is simple, I want to rotate the path by -115.609deg and adjust the position of the path and the height/width of the svg. The second svg is just to show what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I don't understand how I can rotate the path from his own center and also to have a svg size that fit the contents

Comment: Apply a transform to rotate the path. Get the bounding box of the rotated path, ajust the svg size. Job done. No need to mess around with the path values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with JS in the browser.

Note that this works in **Firefox**, but not Chrome (and probably not Safari either) due to the way Chrome calculates the bounding boxes of transformed content.

```js
function rotateAndAdjust(elem, angle)
{
  // Rotate the element by the angle
  elem.setAttribute("transform", "rotate("+angle+")");
  // Call getBBox to get the updated bounding box
  var bbox = elem.parentElement.getBBox();
  // Use the BBox x and y to move the element back into the viewport
  elem.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (-bbox.x) + "," + (-bbox.y)+") rotate(" + angle + ")");
  // Convert the new width and height to integers
  var w = Math.ceil(bbox.width);
  var h = Math.ceil(bbox.height);
  // Update the viewBox
  elem.ownerSVGElement.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h);
  // Update the SVG width and height  
  elem.ownerSVGElement.setAttribute("width", w);
  elem.ownerSVGElement.setAttribute("height", h);
}


rotateAndAdjust( document.querySelector("path"), -115.609 );
```

```css
svg {
  background: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="92" height="63" viewBox="0 0 92 63" fill="none">
<g>
    <path d="M90.6668 0H0L49.9325 61.7586L90.6668 0Z" fill="#6F7800" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Just a clarification. It works in Chrome. You just don't get the tightest bounding box.